# Kestrel on https with asp.net core 1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I want to run Kestrel on https with asp.net core 1.0
I tried to follow this post http://dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-setup-https-on-kestrel/

But it doesn't work with asp.net core

It is giving the error at

`app.UseKestrelHttps(certificate)`

The error is

> Error CS1061  'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseKestrelHttps' and no extension method 'UseKestrelHttps' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That article seems to be about ASP.NET 5 RC1. According to [this post](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/168), in ASP.NET Core, `.UseKestrelHttps()` has been replaced with `options.UseHttps()`, for example:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel(options => {
        options.UseHttps(new X509Certificate2(...));
    })
```

You need to add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https` to your project to get the `UseHttps` functionality.

Comment: Addition: You have to add "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https" to your project.json to see UseHttps()